# How to translate a one-line condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, function, arguments, conditional-statements

I am currently learning JavaScript and I'm trying to translate a code I made, from Python to Javascript.

I would like to know how I can translate an instruction like this:

```py
my_function(arg1, arg2=True if condition else False)
```

I can't find this specific case on Google.

Many thanks!

Comment: Ternary operator is what you are looking for. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are looking for `ternary operator`, it looks like this:

```
const condition = true;
function(arg1, condition ? "true" : "false")
```

The logic behind it:

First argument (before ?) is the condition, e.g:

```
const age = 18
age >= 18 ? ....
```

The second argument (after ?) is the `True` statement and after the `:` is the `False` statement

```
? "Above 18" : "Under 18"
```

Final result:

```
const age = 18;
console.log(age >= 18 ? "Above 18" : "Under 18"); // prints "Above 18"
```